# TinyMce Unisharp Image Display issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, tinymce

I am using a Laravel PHP framework where in I am using TinyMce as text editor and I am using Unisharp's filemanager which is successfully integrated with TinyMce.

When I upload an image it gets successfully gets uploaded in my public folder but when it comes to displaying images it shows an error that "image cannot be found". 
The URL its looking for is 
http://domain-name.com/beta/public/index.php/photos/image.jpg .

Now here if I take this url and remove index.php and paste it in another tab then it shows me the image.

Comment: And which url is running your site, having `public/index.php`?

Comment: yes.The running website url http://domain_name.com/beta/public/index.php

Comment: Ok, so need to remove `public/index.php` from your path via ht access. Did you do that?

Comment: i told my project manager about that ... He said its nothing to do with public/index.php  :(

Comment: So hope you also checked with your PM about last line from your question?

Comment: i told him about this ....but he is not willing to listen .... so i am looking for an alternate solution ..